# sorting of vector of struct according the criteria and then display result

Tags: c++

suppose  we have following struct in c++

```
struct edge
{
    int a, b;
    float weight;//edge  a-b  has weight
    bool operator() (edge x, edge y)
    {
        x.weight < y.weight;


    }
};
```

what i want is to  sort  edges according to weight,  so i  have created  vector of  egdes  and i have sorted, but  i can't display result, let me show you full code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct edge
{
    int a, b;
    float weight;//edge  a-b  has weight
    bool operator() (edge x, edge y)
    {
        x.weight < y.weight;


    }
};
int main()
{
    edge e;
    int Edge;
    cout << "enter number of edge  :";
    cin >> Edge;
    vector<edge>a(Edge);
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
    {
        cin >> e.a >> e.b >> e.weight;
        a.push_back(e);
            }
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(),e);
    vector<edge>::iterator ii;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        cout << a[i] << "  ";
    return 0;

}
```

there is following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands Kruskal_algorithm_c++   c:\Users\dato\Desktop\c++ programs practise\Kruskal_algorithm_c++\Kruskal_algorithm_c++\Kurskal_algorithm_c++.cpp   32
```

how can i fix this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: You don't have a stream insertion operator for your struct. But your comparison is rather strange. Why not just have a less-than operator defined in your struct?

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with sorting?

Comment: enter  result in changed order and  you can see, just only point is how to remove additional zeros

Comment: @datodatuashvili Look at your code carefully.  What does this do? `vector<edge>myvector(Edge);`?  Given the answer, what then does this do in the loop: `myvector.push_back(e);`?  How many total entries are there in the vector after all of that is done?

Comment: to create of edge  with size of given number Edge,  second question, to insert  elements of  edge e into vector

Comment: @datodatuashvili  So if `Edge` is 3, how many total entries, after the loop is done, will there be in the vector?  I'm trying to get you to realize the mistake you're making.

Comment: I rolled back to the original version because the edits had changed the nature of the question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good luck with that.

Comment: for instance we have edges like this (0-1 12, 0-2 10,1-2 9), that is correct right

Comment: @datodatuashvili See my answer.  Obviously you are not reading your code carefully, and / or not understanding what `push_back` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `Edge` is 3.  This line:

```
vector<edge>myvector(Edge);
```

already sizes the `vector` with 3 entries.

Then in the loop, you are calling `push_back`, meaning you are adding more entries at the tail end of the `vector`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
 {
        cin >> e.a >> e.b >> e.weight;
        myvector.push_back(e); 
 }
```

So at the end of all of this, you have `6` total entries in the vector.  The first 3 entries are all 0, and the "real data" was added at the tail end.

You should either:

1) Start out with an **empty vector**, not with a vector with `Edge` elements already in it.

```
vector<edge> myvector;  // an empty vector
for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
{
    cin >> e.a >> e.b >> e.weight;
    myvector.push_back(e); 
}
```

Or

2) Size the vector with `Edge` items, and access each one of the entries in the loop:

```
vector<edge> myvector(Edge);  // size the vector with Edge number of items

for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
{
    cin >> e.a >> e.b >> e.weight;
    myvector[i] = e; // access the item we want
}
```

---

Note that once you have the `std::vector` the proper size, there is no need to further use variables such as `Edge` or any other variable you may or would use to denote the number of entries.  The reason is that the `std::vector` knows its own size by calling `std::vector::size()`.

Having extraneous variables to denote the number of entries increases the chances that bugs may appear (the number of entries in the vector may change and you forget to update this "size" variable, for example).  Bottom line, always use `std::vector::size()` to give you the number of entries.

Comment: aaaaaaaa, clear clear, i got point thanks in advance, sorry i am recalling c++ after  several years, so  by practise i am  get using it

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `operator<<` for `edge` structure e.g.:

```
struct edge
{
    int a, b;
    float weight;//edge  a-b  has weight
    bool operator() (edge x, edge y)
    {
        x.weight < y.weight;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const edge& obj);
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const edge& obj)
{
    os << "a = " << obj.a << " b = " << obj.b << " weight = " << obj.weight;
    return os;
}
```

**EDIT**:

You also use vector not quite as you intended:

```
vector<edge> myvector(Edge); // creates a vector of 'Edge' elements initialized with default constructor
// ...
myvector.push_back(e); // Adds element instead of intended overwriting
```

You should use either:

```
vector<edge> myvector; // initializes empty vector
```

or

```
myvector.at(i) = e; // overwrites element of the vector
```

Comment: @datodatuashvili Your solution also works fine. The difference is that in my solution you don't need to know object internals in client code.

Comment: yes but there is some  week points, can you see black screen?  result is displayed incorrectly

Comment: i think  solution is based on make_pair function

Comment: @datodatuashvili Why?

Comment: to insert triple element in vector,  have you seen  screenshot ? black window

Comment: @datodatuashvili -- Please look more carefully at your code.  The issue has nothing to do with `pairs` or "triple elements",

Comment: so what kind of changes  are necessary in my code ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili you have a vector of objects that contain 3 fields, but vector knows nothing about the element internals.  Just try my code.

Comment: @datodatuashvili just write instead of `vector<edge> myvector(Edge);` this : `vector<edge> myvector;`

Comment: @datodatuashvili in this case you use `push_back()`

Comment: @datodatuashvili Just mark your question answered )